# kinit gives me a Kerberos ticket, but no AFS token

Tags: security, filesystems, kerberos, afs

I'm trying to setup access to my university's IT environment from my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04, by (mostly) following the IT-department's guides on [AFS](http://www.pdc.kth.se/resources/software/file-transfer/file-transfer-with-afs/linux/afs-in-ubuntu) and [Kerberos](http://www.pdc.kth.se/resources/software/login-1/linux/ubuntu).

I can get AFS working well enough so that I can navigate to my home folder (located in the nada.kth.se cell of AFS), and I can get Kerberos working well enough to forward tickets and authenticate me when I connect with ssh. However, I don't seem to get any AFS tokens locally, on my machine, so I can't just go to /afs/nada.kth.se/.../folder/file.txt on my machine and edit it. I can't even stand in /afs/nada.kth.se/.../folder and run `ls` without getting Permission denied errors.

Why doesn't `kinit -f myusername@NADA.KTH.SE` give me an AFS token? What do I need to do to get one?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the answer is "run `aklog`" (or `afslog` from Heimdal -- either should work).  If you're using Heimdal Kerberos (which I suspect you are at KTH), try adding the `--afslog` flag to `kinit`.